# Why is this inhomogeneous Sobolev embedding saying anything?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, littlewood-paley-theory

I'm reading *Nonlinear dispersive equations: local and global analysis* by Terrance Tao and on page 335 he states the following theorem:

if $1 < p < q < \infty$ and $1/p < 1/q + s/d$ then

$$\| f \|_{L_x^q(\mathbb{R}^d)} \lesssim_{p, s, q, d} \| f \|_{W_x^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)}.$$

As I understand this, this means that there is some constant, $C > 0$, which depends on $p, s, q, \text{ and } d$ such that

$$\| f \|_{L_x^q(\mathbb{R}^d)} \leq C \| f \|_{W_x^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)}.$$

But, this seems trivial to me. The only variables in play are $p, s, q, \text{ and } d$ and the quantities $\| f \|_{L_x^q(\mathbb{R}^d)}$ and $\| f \|_{W_x^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)}$ are just some real constants so, of course, one is less than a constant factor of the other. I suppose if the right hand side were zero and the left hand side were not, then this would say something more, but I suspect I'm just misunderstanding what the theorem is getting at.

Comment: The $C$ is not allowed to depend on $f$. If it were allowed to, then of course such inequalities are trivial. Your wording definitely makes $C$ dependent on $f$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Oh! I assumed (incorrectly, my bad) that $C$ was (implicitly) dependent on $f$. With what you said, that makes these *extremely* interesting. Thank you! (Btw, where does my wording make it seem like $C$ depends on $f$? I don't see it, but maybe we're finding a blind spot of mine).

Comment: “and the quantities $\| f \|_{L_x^q(\mathbb{R}^d)}$ and $\| f \|_{W_x^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)}$ are just some real constants so, of course, one is less than a constant factor of the other”